# Gulp Error: task completion callback called too many times

Tags: angular, gulp

I have:

```
gulp.task("remove:tsConfigs", function (cb) {
    rimraf('./wwwroot/js/ng2-toastr/tsconfig.json', cb);
    rimraf('./wwwroot/js/reflect-metadata/tsconfig.json', cb);
});
```

and I get task completion callback called too many times

I saw several posts that this is a problem with async. I dont know how to fix it though

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the two `rimraf` lines calls the `cb` callback. However you are only allowed to call `cb` once.

You have to use nested callbacks so that `cb` is only called after both `rimraf` have been executed:

```
gulp.task("remove:tsConfigs", function (cb) {
    rimraf('./wwwroot/js/ng2-toastr/tsconfig.json', function() {
       rimraf('./wwwroot/js/reflect-metadata/tsconfig.json', cb);
    });
});
```

Honestly though, I'd recommend using [`del`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del) instead. It's a just promise wrapper around `rimraf`, which means you don't have to deal with the callback at all and it allows you to delete multiple files/folders at once:

```
var del = require('del');

gulp.task("remove:tsConfigs", function () {
    return del(['./wwwroot/js/ng2-toastr/tsconfig.json',
                './wwwroot/js/reflect-metadata/tsconfig.json']);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I will use the 'del' as nesting is quite complex and not maintainable. I have also found that rimraf is deprecated in favor of del.